# ASP.NET MVC AjaxForm not updating partial view properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I have never had this problem before or maybe I have, but I've never noticed. I have a page with a partial view. When the page is submitted, the model is checked to see if it has an ID. If it does, it updates the record. If not, it creates a new one. Pretty standard. Once it is done, the model is returned back to the view. The problem I seem to be having is that it isn't updated with any changes to the model. It is just the same model that was posted. Okay so here is some code. I created a brand new project and it still doesn't work.

Also, I used Firebug to look at the raw data coming back and it is still the same model.

Here is the controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return this.View(new Test());
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult TestDetailPost(Test testin)
{
    Test test = new Test();
    test.Id = "1";
    test.Name = "Guy";

    return this.PartialView("TestDetail", test);
}
```

Here is the "Test" view:

```
@model WebAppTest.Models.Test
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestDetailPost", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "TestDetail" }))
{
    <p><input type="submit"/></p>
    <div id="TestDetail">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("TestDetail", Model); }
    </div>
}
```

Here is the "Test Detail" view:

```
@model WebAppTest.Models.Test
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Id)</p>
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Name)</p>
```

And the model:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So what I have found is that if I remove the "Test testin" from the TestDetailPost action, it returns the model I created. If I don't, it just returns the same model that was posted. Of course, I am not doing any DB saves or anything, the code above is just for trying to figure out why this is happening.

Here is the details of what I am using:

MVC5
jQuery 1.11.1
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax

I have updated all files to the latest version using NuGet.

Comment: Are you including the jquery-unobtrusive at the main view?

Comment: iso @{ Html.RenderPartial("TestDetail", Model); } try @Html.Partial("TestDetail", Model)

Comment: @Fals - Yes, I have jquery-unobtrusive. It works fine if I remove "Test testin" from "TestDetailPost(Test testin)".

Comment: @Devcon2 - That doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Probly you are getting some exception. Take a look at the Google Chrome Console to see if something went wrong.

Comment: @Fals - no errors at all. I've been using Firebug and there are no errors.

Comment: So I found out something else about this, if I change the "Test testin" from "TestDetailPost(Test testin)" to something like "string testin" it works fine. It appears it only breaks if I pass the same object model that I received back out. Sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Call `ModelState.Clear();` in your action method like below:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult TestDetailPost(Test testin)
{
   ModelState.Clear();
   Test test = new Test();
   test.Id = "1";
   test.Name = "Guy";

   return this.PartialView("TestDetail", test);
}
```

I have given more details in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654879/mvc4-html-textboxfor-not-working-after-modifying-viewmodel/13661940#13661940). I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, that fixed it. I've never really ran into this problem. It is really weird and unusual. Thanks for the help and the great explanation!

Comment: Wow, been fighting gremlins in the system for 3 hours before finding this.  Ugh.  Thank you for posting.