# View does NOT update

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a `view` like this:

```
<div class="container content-sm">
    @{
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <a>my profile</a>
        }
        else
        {
            if (Request.Url != null)
            {
                <a>Log in</a>
            }
        }
    }
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="blog-item">
            some html tags ...
        </div>
        <div>
            <a>Next article</a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
        <div class="post-comment hidden-print" id="comment-tool-box">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveComment", "News", new { id = Model.Blog.Id }, new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                UpdateTargetId = "CommentToolPanel",
                LoadingElementId = "loader",
                OnBegin = "OnBegin",
                OnSuccess = "OnComplete",
                OnFailure = "OnFailure"
            }, new {@class = "my-form"}))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.Partial("_PartialComment")
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and `controller`:

```
    [Route("en-us/blogs/explore/show/{year}/{month}/{day}/{id}/{title}")]
    public ActionResult Details(string year, string month, string day, int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var model = _db.Table.ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Log(exception);
            return View("Index");
        }
    }

    public string Captcha(int id)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));
        var obj = new RandomStringGenerator(true, true, true, false)
        {
            MinLowerCaseCharacters = 2,
            MinNumericCharacters = 2,
            MinUpperCaseCharacters = 2
        };
        var input = obj.Generate(7);
        var bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        var font = new Font("Arial", 20f);
        var stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(input, font);
        bmp = new Bitmap
            (
            bmp,
            (int)stringSize.Width,
            (int)stringSize.Height
            );
        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graphics.DrawString(input, font, Brushes.LightGray, 0, 0);
        font.Dispose();
        graphics.Flush();
        graphics.Dispose();
        var width = bmp.Width;
        var height = bmp.Height;
        var tmp = new Random();
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                var r = tmp.Next(0, 255);
                var g = tmp.Next(0, 255);
                var b = tmp.Next(0, 255);
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b));
                y++;
            }
            x++;
        }
        MemoryStream stream;
        using (stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        var image = stream.ToArray();

        var imageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
        var imageDataUrl = $"data:image/png;base64,{imageBase64Data}";
        var captchaImage =
            $"<a data-ajax=\"true\" data-ajax-mode=\"replace\" data-ajax-update=\"#capt1\" href=\"/News/Captcha\"><img src='{imageDataUrl}' title=\"Click to reload a new image\" /></a>";

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["maCaptcha"] = input;

        Session["maCaptcha"] = input;

        return captchaImage;
    }
```

and `_PartialComment` view

```
<div id="CommentToolPanel" class="hidden-print">
<header>Leave a Comment</header>
<fieldset>
    <section>
            @{
                var opts1 = new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = "capt1"
                };
            }
            <span id="capt1">
                @Html.Action("Captcha", "News")
            </span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CaptchaString, new
            {
                id = "captchaImage",
                name = "captchaImage",
                type = "text",
                placeholder = "Captcha code is case censitive."
            })
    </section>
</fieldset>
<footer>
            <button type="submit" class="button" id="btnComment">Submit</button>
</footer>
```

first time that the view is load, every things are fine, but, when I refresh the browser, `Details` method in controller does not fire, however the content of page will renew. 
Let's say there are 2 records in database. First time, the record #1 is displayed (so far so good), with click next, record #2 will displayed too (seems fine), now, I try to display record #1 again, it will, but `Details` method does not fired.
 So, my problem is: if user is logged in and browse the page and after that logged out and then return to this page, the **my profile** link is still displays, because, the view is not updated.
I try these things:
[ASP.NET MVC AjaxForm not updating partial view properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817025/asp-net-mvc-ajaxform-not-updating-partial-view-properly)
[Update A Div And Partial View Using Ajax.BeginForm On Form Submit](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4fcb5a/update-a-div-and-partial-view-using-ajax-beginform-on-form-s/)
[[Walkthrough] Updating Partial Views with Unobtrusive AJAX in MVC 3](http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/08/03/walkthrough-updating-partial-views-with-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-3.aspx)
[View not updating after post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645479/view-not-updating-after-post)
but not helped :(

Edit:
Problem will solved, when I removed this part of code from _PartialComment view:

    
        @Html.Action("Captcha", "News")
    
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CaptchaString, new
    {
        id = "captchaImage",
        name = "captchaImage",
        type = "text",
        placeholder = "Captcha code is case censitive."
    })

Would you please tell me what is(are) my mistake(s) nor which part(s) is(are) wrong? 
How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

By removing these lines in `Captcha` method, my problem is solved!!!

```
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));
```

and I don't know why.